# Android MeasureUnit to Proto Datastore

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, protocol-buffers, datastore

I want to save a value to datastore with MeasureUnit type.

I know it is not possible but for better explain here is what I want to:

```
message Pref {
    MeasureUnit unit = 1
}
```

and set like:

```
pref.setUnit(MeasureUnit.CENTIMETER)
```

How can I do this with Proto Datastore ?